# Why is detecting touches getting slower and slower?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my game if I play a particular game for several times, my touches need more time to be detected.
It stores all touches and then applies those touches all at the same time.

Can anybody tell me what's the problem?

In `touchesBegan` I wrote:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint([tapView frame], [touch locationInView:self])
    && tapView.alpha == 1) {
    [self callTapCode];
}
```

This is the code of `touchesEnded`. If I tapped and release the tapped it shows one tapping event.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (checkTap == TRUE && tapView.alpha == 1 )
        tap_effect_view.alpha = 0;
}

- (void)callTapCode {
    // Move player code by 6 pixels
    // not possible to write all code
}
```

In `tapView` I continuously tap. `callTapCode` moves the player by six pixels. But after some time my touches detected very slowly, so that the player looks like he's jumping around. I played the game continuously 15 to 16 times.

Comment: Do you have a reduced code sample that demonstrates the basic elements of the issue?

Comment: in touchesBegan i write

if(CGRectContainsPoint([tapView frame],[touch locationInView:self]) &&tapView.alpha==1 )
 {  
  [self callTapCode];
 }
In tapView i m continuously tapping. callTapCode method move user Player by six pixels. But after sometime my touches detected very slow.

Comment: so player looks jumping. I i played the game continuously 15 to 16 times

Comment: You should edit this new information into the question, where it is visible.

Comment: The code you gave us is of little use, we still have to guess the internal working. Please give us something about touchesEnded and callTabCode.

Comment: Why have you removed the code?

Comment: I think in order to be able to help, you have to supply some more information and/or code.

Comment: This is code in touchesEnded  if I tapped and release the tapped it shows one tapping effect.
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
 if(checkTap==TRUE&&tapView.alpha==1)
    tap_effect_view.alpha=0;
}

Comment: -(void)callTapCode
{//Move player code by 6 pixels
//not possible to write all code
}

Comment: Edit the question next time instead of posting a lot of code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You might work through this [tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) to learn how to use the **Leaks** Instrument. This is part of the Instruments suite that comes with Xcode, which will, among other things, help you track down memory leaks and general performance issues with your application.

Comment: Ya i also use this but it does not make lot of difference

Comment: What does Leaks report when you create touch events (when you touch the screen)? I would recommend that you go through the tutorial so that you can learn this tool. It really is quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. In my game I had enabled the `tapView.multipleTouchEnabled = TRUE`

`tapView` is the view where I was continuously tapping.

When I make it `FALSE` it works.

i.e.

```
tapView.multipleTouchEnabled = FALSE;
```

I exactly dont know how. But it works.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for any memory leaks. Maybe the iPhone has to use virtual memory a lot.

Comment: In my game when i am tapping there is one user player. when i tapped on tapView once it moves the player by 6 pixels. How much fast i tapped it moves the player. But after some times means if i play my game 16 to 18 times it detect the tap very slow.

Comment: It applies all the remaining tap at time on player so player looks like jumping. to check whether processors are slow i just call the same tap code in timer and run the game 20 to 25 times but it works fine. Means its not issue of processor slow so can u help me

Comment: Do you release the stored touches? And how do you do it?

Comment: And try to write 'you' instead of 'u'. and instead of 'i': 'I'. It gets easy after a while.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the suggestion I will always remember it.

Comment: I don't know how to release the stored touches? If you know can u please tell me. :)

Comment: That depends on the code you have in [self callTapCode] I think.